# How to say blood sugar in Esperanto

Tags: translation

I am type 1 diabetic, and since I learned Esperanto I have been wondering how to say "blood sugar". Is it:

> Sanga sukero (a direct translation which I bet is very wrong)

> suka sango (this seems like "juicy blood")

> sukera sango (same, but "sugary blood")

> suko de sango (my favorite, because it is sort of like the level of juice in the blood)

> sukeroj de sango (adding eroj seems a little unnesisary)

> sukero de sango (it seems a little weird in the singular, like one grain of sugar)

> sukeraĵo de sango (would it need to be aĵo?)

Let me know what you think! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eduardo pravas, ke en ĉiutaga interparolado la esprimo "sukero en (la) sango" sufiĉas. Kvankam ekzistas tia neoficiala sufikso "-emio", mi dubas, kiom multaj homoj konas ĝin (ekz. mi neniam antaŭe aŭdis ĝin), kaj ĉi tial mi hezitos uzi ĝin.

Ĉar fakte temas pri kvanto de glukozo en sango, pli klaraj estas "glukozenhavo (en sango)" kaj "glukoznivelo (en sango)".

Notu, ke en la angla esprimo "blood sugar" la ideo de enhaveco aŭ nivelo estas subkomprenata, kaj en Esperanto oni ofte klopodas eviti tiajn subkomprenaĵojn.

Comment: Interese! Dankon :-) Mi sxatas glukoznivelo :-) Tamen, kial "sukero en sango" anstataux "suko en sango", kial la sufikso "ero" necesas?

Comment: Ĥa, sukero ne estas suko + ero, sed alia afero ol suko. La unua estas "sugar" angle kaj la dua "juice".

Comment: Ho, bonege!  Dankon :-)

Answer (score 2):

En ĉiutaga interparolado vi povus diri ion kiel `sukero en sango` ĉar el kuracscienca vidpunkto, vi priparolas nek sangon, nek sukeron, sed *mezuritan kvanton* de iu specifa sukero en sango: [glukozo](https://vortaro.net/#glukozo_kdc).

Ekzistas neoficiala sufikso [-emi-](https://vortaro.net/#emio_kdc) ĝuste por *kvanto de io en sango*. Ekzemple `alkoholemio` estas la kvanto de alkoholo en sango.

Tiu sufikso produktas la vorton `glukozemio`, kiun vi povas uzi kiel tradukon de `blood sugar (level)`. Pro tio ke temas pri kvanto, vi povas aldoni adjektivon por diri ĉu estas troa, nesufiĉa, alta, malalta, ... Vi povas ankaŭ mencii la faktan kvanton: *mia glukozemio hodiaŭ estas X* (la mezurunuon oni tre verŝajne subkomprenas).

```
blood sugar (level) -> glukoz-emi-o
```

Comment: En PIV 2020 estas glukozemio.

Answer (score 1):

Kiel diabetulo mi uzas:

```
Mi rapide mezuras mian (sango)sukeron.
```

Por la indiki la gradon: **sukereco**